# Saving an imageView in SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, imageview, sharedpreferences

I am trying to save an imageView to SharedPreferences however nothing seems to be working.
Is there anything which I can implement in order to store an imageView to sharedPreferences?

Comment: store uri to shared preference not imageview..

Answer (score 1):

An `ImageView` is a graphical component. You can't store it in `SharedPreferences`.

If you are talking about the Image, you can store its Uri or its ID if it is a Resource (Drawable, Asset, etc.)

To obtain `SharedPreferences`, use the following method:

```
private static final String URI_KEY = "URI_KEY";
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To save preferences:

```
prefs.edit().putString(URI_KEY, uri).apply();
```

To read preferences:

```
String uri = prefs.getString(URI_KEY, "");
```